# is `this` invisible in a json callback?

Tags: javascript, scope, coffeescript

the following JS code is being produced from [CoffeeScript](http://jashkenas.github.com/coffee-script) equivalent.

I want to add objects to a slider widget, properties of these objects come from a [Django REST view](http://django-rest-framework.org/), nothing fancy, just a list of dictionaries.

I am very new to both CoffeeScript and Django and I don't understand the visibility of `this`.

of the two versions here, one works, the other doesn't.

```
Slider.prototype.manageObject = function(itemId, colorSequence) {
  var obj;
  obj = this;
  return $.getJSON("http://localhost:8000/api/?item=" + itemId, function(data) {
    return obj.managed.push([itemId, data]);
  });
};

Slider.prototype.manageObject = function(itemId, colorSequence) {
  return $.getJSON("http://localhost:8000/api/?item=" + itemId, function(data) {
    return this.managed.push([itemId, data]);
  });
};
```

why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that value of `this` depends on the context. It usually refers to the current object, which in the second case is the callback function. By assigning `obj = this` you keep the original reference to `Slider` in the variable `obj`, therefore calling `managed.push` works, in the second case you are trying to call `managed.push` function on the callback function which doesn't exist.

A really great explanation of `this`: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/this.html and http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/08/30/understanding-javascripts-this/

Answer (score 2):

In the second version `this` variable within `$.getJSON` points to `jQuery` object. While in the first you store the reference the much needed `this` to the `obj` variable. And then simply access it.

**+** Just to be more clear, on the 3rd line of your code fragment `this` points to `Slider.prototype`.

Comment: guys, thanks you all.  I'm going to accept one at random among the two answers I understood better.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript doesn't have a distinction between methods and functions so *all* functions receive a hidden `this` variable. The this is determined by how you call the function:

Functions called using dot "method" notation will have `this` set to the appropriate object:

```
obj.method(args);
//this inside method will be obj
```

Functions called by themselves receive a useless `this` that you shouls not use. This is arguably a design mistake since inheriting the this from the parent function would be much more useful

```
getJson( ..., function(result){
    //we are inside another function now
    //it has its own useless "this" that shadows the one that you actually want
});
```

The usual workaroud is doing precisely what you originaly did, by setting a normal variable to the original "this" and using it instead. It is common practice to call the variable `that`

```
var that = this;
getJson(..., function(){
    that.managed ///...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The callback is called after the **asynchronous** request is made. Therefore, the callback is called in a different scope than in what is declared and the `this` keyword will refer to something else than you'd expect. Because it is defined in the same closure as the `obj` variable, the function can access the initial `this` value stored in that auxiliary variable.

Answer (score 0):

In example 1 "this" refers to the Slider function where as in example 2 "this" is being called in the callback executed by $.getJSON() function so it points to the $.getJSON function